# Support back button with the same URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, back-button

I've done my share of research but failed to find any reliable option.
I've a AJAX-based mobile web app, developed in Spring MVC and want to support both the browser's back button as well as a button of the same function in the layout itself.

Can anyone show me some alternatives? FYI, I'm using jquery, so plugins for that are welcomed in diminuishing dependencies.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the history api to add history entries to the page so that the back button could be used to trigger an event that your app then responds to.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that please?

Comment: No, however i can provide a guide that was the result of a quick search: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history (note, any time you are searching for documentation for web/javascript methods, add "mdn" to the search text. For example, "history api mdn")